# How to loop through mails in Exchange using EWS?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007, exchangewebservices

I've been given the task of fetching a list of the largest mails in our Exchange 2007 server.

Since I've never coded against Exchange before, I looked around a bit and figured EWS is the newest interface to do so.

However I can't find any documentation about looping through the mails, which I expect to be necessary to check the sizes.

Does anyone have a code sample, a link or pretty much anything, which could help me accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres examples of iterating through messages here and doing multiple functions (searching/sorting etc). Should be of help.

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exchange/EWSPart2.aspx)